# azure logging wrapper import from another file - not working

Tags: python, azure, logging, appinsights

i'm having some issues with a logging wrapper i createed. the repo structure is this one:

```
├───auth
│   └───auth_handler.py
└───logger.py
```

inside the auth_handler i have some functions that are used by some fastapi endpoints. the wrapper is this one:

```
def log_function_call(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logger = logging.getLogger(env_logger)
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        properties = {
            "custom_dimensions": {
                "func_name": func.__name__,
                "elapsed": end_time - start_time,
                "args": args,
                "kwargs": kwargs,
                "return": result,
            }
        }
        logger.log(
            logging.INFO,
            msg=f"Calling {func.__name__} elapsed: {end_time-start_time}",
            extra=properties,
        )
        return result

    return wrapper
```

and it is initialized with a yaml config file with a stream and a Azure handler (with opencensus).
the problem i'm facing is that whenever i make a call to the endpoints using the decorated functions, the log is created in stream but not on Azure. if i just use the logger created it works fine.

i'm assuming the problem is the disposition of the files inside the folder, because if i try to call the decorator with a function at the same level as the logger.py file it works, like in this case:

```
├───auth
│   └───auth_handler.py
└───logger.py
└───test.py
```

where test.py is something like

```
import logger as lg


@lg.log_function_call
def func(test):
    return test
```

here the yaml configuration file:

```
version: 1
formatters:
  detailedFormatter:
    format: "%(asctime)s loglevel=%(levelname)-6s logger=%(name)s %(funcName)s() L%(lineno)-4d %(message)s   call_trace=%(pathname)s L%(lineno)-4d"
  detailedFormatterAzure:
    format: "loglevel=%(levelname)-6s logger=%(name)s %(funcName)s() L%(lineno)-4d %(message)s   call_trace=%(pathname)s L%(lineno)-4d"

handlers:
  consoleHandler:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: detailedFormatter
    stream: ext://sys.stdout

  fileHandler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    filename: log.log  
    formatter: detailedFormatter

  azureHandler:
    class: opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter.AzureLogHandler
    connection_string: 
    formatter: detailedFormatterAzure
    level: INFO
    
loggers:
    development:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [azureHandler,consoleHandler]
        propagate: no

    staging:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [consoleHandler]
        propagate: no

    production:
        level: WARNING
        handlers: [consoleHandler]
        propagate: no

root:
  level: INFO
  handlers: [consoleHandler, azureHandler]
```

- connection string is missing here for obvious reasons :D

Comment: Can you share your yaml config file?

Comment: i edited the question! i omitted the connection string of azure here. thanks :D

Comment: Are you trying call the logger file in auth_handler right?

Comment: exactly, i want the logger wrapper to be usable by auth_handler. it is straming the logs and also writing them on the file (if i also include in the development environment the fileHandler), but it is not logging on azure :'( 

the logger is configured when the back end is activated.

Comment: are you able to getting those logs in local?

Comment: Yep, in local no problem. I cannot see them on azure

Answer (score 0):

> the problem i'm facing is that whenever i make a call to the endpoints using the decorated functions, the log is created in stream but not on Azure.

By using decorated functions to call the wrapper function and able to get the logs local and azure.
I have configured application insights in yaml file by using appinsights connection string.

- To ensure that give correct Import statements to import the functions into another file.

**Folder structure:**

[image]

- Make sure to give correct connection string in config.yaml.

**Config.yaml**

```
handlers:
  consoleHandler:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: detailedFormatter
    stream: ext://sys.stdout

  azureHandler:
    class: opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter.AzureLogHandler
    connection_string: "your-conn-string"
    formatter: detailedFormatterAzure
    level: INFO
    
loggers:
    development:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [azureHandler, consoleHandler]
        propagate: no

root:
  level: INFO
  handlers: [consoleHandler, azureHandler]
```

**Main.py**

```
from auth.auth_handler import authenticate_user
import logging.config
import yaml

def main():
    # Load logging configuration from config.yaml
    with open('config.yaml', 'r') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)

    result = authenticate_user("test_user", "test_password")
    print("Authentication result:", result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Auth_handler.py**

```
from  logger  import  log_function_call

@log_function_call
def  authenticate_user(username, password):
# Perform authentication logic here
# For demonstration purposes, let's assume the authentication is successful
    return  True
```

**Output in Local:**

[image]

Getting logs in azure as well, check below:

[image]